# Why do I get a "301 Moved Permanently" error by making a HTTP request with TcpClient?

Tags: c#, http, tcpclient

Basically, I'm making a HTTP library, so I'm using TcpClient to create a socket connection and send the HTTP headers and stuff.

Now I can get the HTML of google.com, but I can't for pastebin.com and stackoverflow.com for example, as when I try that, I keep getting a "301 Moved Permanently" error, no matter what. Also, the **"Location" section is the same as the input url**, so I don't get it : **Why is it broken like that?**

Here is the code that makes the request :

```
var parsedUrl = ParseUrl();

var array = parsedUrl.Split('/');
var host = array[0];
var subpages = array[1];

Socket = new TcpClient(host, 80)
{
    ReceiveBufferSize = BufferSize
};
var buffer = new byte[BufferSize];

var headers = new StringBuilder();
headers.AppendLine("GET /" + subpages + " HTTP/1.1");
headers.AppendLine("Host: " + host);
foreach (var header in Headers) headers.AppendLine(header);
headers.AppendLine();
headers.AppendLine();

Socket.SendBufferSize = headers.Length;

var sent = Socket.Client.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(headers.ToString()));
var received = Socket.Client.Receive(buffer);

var response = new RawResponseNET()
{
    Url = parsedUrl,
    BufferSize = BufferSize,
    BytesSent = sent,
    BytesReceived = received,
    Request = this,
    Buffer = buffer,
    SocketStream = Socket.GetStream(),
    BufferIndex = BinaryMatch(buffer, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n\r\n")) + 4
};
response.ResponseHeaders = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, response.BufferIndex);

Socket.Close();

return response;
```

The `RawResponseNET` class just contains a method named `ToString()` that will just parse the response as a string.

The headers that I add (excluding Host) are `Accept: text/html, charset=utf-8` and `Connection: close`. I've tried adding some more headers (including some when my web browser does a request) but no luck.

Here is what the response headers look like for **pastebin.com** :

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sat, 03 Oct 2020 12:50:09 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Expires: Sat, 03 Oct 2020 13:50:09 GMT
Location: https://www.pastebin.com/
cf-request-id: 05901c48e80000ee2ffca20200000001
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 5dc6c987ddcbee2f-CDG
```

So then, my final question is : **How would I fix that problem?**

Comment: Out of interest, why are you making an HTTP library from scratch? Is this just an exercise to learn how things work at a lower level?

Comment: Why don't you use WebClient instead?

Comment: @trenki If I'm making a library, I sure won't use something built-in.

Comment: @John it's to know how things work at a lower level, as you said.

Comment: I think in the HTTP 301 case you need to make another request to the Location: https://www.pastebin.com/ as indicated in the response header

Comment: @trenki But then that wouldn't make much sense since the Location is **exactly** the same.

Comment: Is your original request to `http://` or `https://`? The redirect for pastebin is to `https://`

Comment: @John By default it's http (so port 80), but if I change the port to 443 I get a 400 Bad Request error.

Comment: 443 is the port for https, you will need to make a connection over TLS

Comment: @mousetail I've tried making a connection with SslStream but I still get that 301 Moved Permanently error.

Comment: So if you make a TLS encrypted connection to port 443 you get a redirect to the exact same page with the exact same protocol? You must be using either the wrong port or wrong protocol

Comment: If there is https:// in the input url, the port is 443, else it's 80. And by wrong protocol what do you mean?